# How to wrap multiple stack screens with context provider in react navigation 5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I would like to achieve something like the following but it is not possible because stack navigator accepts only Stack.Screens as children.

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Provider1>
    <Stack.Screen name="screen1" component={Screen1} />
    <Stack.Screen name="screen2" component={Screen2} />
  </Provider1>
  <Provider2>
    <Stack.Screen name="screen3" component={Screen3} />
    <Stack.Screen name="screen4" component={Screen4} />
  </Provider2>
</Stack.Navigator/>
```

I know that I could achieve this by wrapping the screens with stack navigator like so:

```
const stackNav1 = <Provider1>
 <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="screen1" component={Screen1} />
    <Stack.Screen name="screen2" component={Screen2} />
 </Stack.Navigator>
</Provider1> 


const stackNav2 = <Provider2>
 <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="screen3" component={Screen3} />
    <Stack.Screen name="screen4" component={Screen4} />
 </Stack.Navigator>
</Provider2> 
...

<Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="stack1" component={stackNav1} />
    <Stack.Screen name="stack2" component={stackNav2} />
</Stack.Navigator/>
```

Is there any simpler approaches in which I wouldn't have to define new navigators?

Comment: Where you able to achieve it? if so can you post the code please

Comment: @ThanveerShah Unfortunately not

Comment: I was able to, But then One set of Navigator has to be bottom navigation :(

Comment: Have you got the solution, If Yes then please share it

Comment: Have you got the solution a year after? Or there's simply no way

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was just defining the context in global scope and then limit access by throwing error based on some condition in the hooks that consume the context.

So for example:

```
const useSomeProperty = () => {
   const { someProperty } = useContext(SomeGlobalContext)

   if (!someProperty) throw new Error("This property can not be accessed here")

   return someProperty
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this, I might be wrong

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Provider1>
   <Stack.Group>
    <Stack.Screen name="screen1" component={Screen1} />
    <Stack.Screen name="screen2" component={Screen2} />
   </Stack.Group>
  </Provider1>
  <Provider2>
   <Stack.Group>
    <Stack.Screen name="screen3" component={Screen3} />
    <Stack.Screen name="screen4" component={Screen4} />
   </Stack.Group>
  </Provider2>
</Stack.Navigator/>
```

Comment: Stack.Group is a feature in React Navigation v6, not v5 as stated in the question

Comment: And this doesn't work anyway. v6 StackNavigator only accepts `Group`, `Screen` and fragments as children, as seen [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/e5e2151b7800d7d627fd7a17e3819e70c0f106d4/packages/core/src/useNavigationBuilder.tsx#L80)